# Moment.js not working on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for local time formatting. It's working fine with initially loaded elements but when the elements are loaded via ajax, the time formatting (moment.js) is not working.

My initializing code for moment.js:

```
$(function () {
    var htmlLang = $('html')[0].lang;
    moment.locale(htmlLang);
    $( "[data-time-format]" ).each(function() {
        var el = $( this );
        switch(el.attr("data-time-format")) {
            case "time-ago":
                var timeValue = el.attr("data-time-value");
                var timeAgoStr = moment.utc(timeValue).fromNow();
                el.text(timeAgoStr);
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

my ajax loader would look like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/path/loadData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { jsondata:jsondata },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
          $("container").append(response);
          //I guess I have to reinitialize moment.js
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Data not loaded.");
        }
      });
```

Comment: You need to call the function again after loading  - there is no event here

Comment: Not reinitialise, but you need to run it again

Comment: Inside the `success` after you insert new elements

Comment: So `function formatTimeAgo() { $( "[data-time-format=time-ago]" ).each(function() { var timeValue = $(this).attr("data-time-value"); var timeAgoStr = moment.utc(timeValue).fromNow(); $(this).text(timeAgoStr);});}` and call `formatTimeAgo()` onload and in success

Comment: @mplungjan To be fair, as you say, there's no event here, so I'm not sure that's the right dupe. You can't really apply the answers to that question to this one...

Comment: @HereticMonkey found another one

Comment: @mplungjan I like the second one you added.

Comment: it works now @mplungjan. I would like to accept your comment as my answer if you make it an answer :) .

Comment: It’s ok - enjoy